# Is there a way to log all incoming Push Notifications in OS X El Capitan (v 10.11.4)?

Tags: macos, automator, notifications, apns

I need the ability to write all incoming Push Notifications (APNS) to a log file. Basically, I would like to end up with an ongoing record of all the Push Notifications that I receive. What is the best way for a newbie to do this in El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Growl](http://growl.info). It can be configured to logs all the events including Push Notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check-out Growl now.